# How to set identity_insert to on in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, identity

I get the command `set identity_insert table_name on;`, but for some reason it is not actually changing the attribute. I've done it with the account that I created the table with, and I've also created an 'admin' account and gave it permissions to do anything (to the best of my knowledge).

Whenever I run the command under either account I get the result of '0 rows affected', then I am unable to run the query to insert the rows I wish to insert with the following error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table_name' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Additionally I've tried to include the schema name in the query like:

```
set identity_insert mySchema.table_name on;
```

but I get the following error:

> Cannot find the object "mySchema.table_name" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Also of note, my project looks like:

```
localhost\SQLEXPRESS
-Databases
--System Databases
--mySchema
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5):

You are using the [right syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms188059.aspx):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.sometable ON;
```

However, a schema in SQL Server is [not the same as a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323740/difference-between-database-and-schema).

The default schema for objects is `dbo` as in my example. You do not need to specify the database name if you are connected to it, but you could like this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT DbName.dbo.sometable ON;
```

There seems to be no way to get the current setting as it is [session-scoped and not persisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637976/how-do-you-check-if-identity-insert-is-set-to-on-or-off-in-sql-server).

If you run this query in your database it returns the fully qualified names for all tables in there:

```
SELECT 
    QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+'.'+
    QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id))+'.'+
    QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) AS FullTableName 
FROM sys.tables;
```

`SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON...` must be run in the same session as the insert.