# Recreate broken Database

Tags: sql-server, recovery, corruption

Here is the scenario - I have a Database that is suffering from Error 824, dbcc checkdb repair_allow_loss has not rectified it and unfortunately the Backups are also corrupt.

However, I am able to query the individual tables and it spits out Data.

I do have a Schema only backup of the Database - however when I try to insert into the new DB using a select query from the old DB, it errors because some of the tables have auto-increment rows.

Ideally, I'd just use SSMS to generate scripts to re-create the Database - but all those functions currently fail because the DB isn't healthy.

The main thing I care about is getting the Data out of the Tables of the broken DB and into one that is working.

If someone can advise how to do this for a single Table, then I can loop through all the tables and fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set identity\_insert to on in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50816/how-to-set-identity-insert-to-on-in-sql-server)

Comment: I may be able to use that, I'm looking for a solution that is more auto-magic, kinda like the equivalent of using -force in powershell. If I have to go through each column on each table and turn it off, that may work - but I'm looking for something less manual.

Comment: Is importing the data using the import/export wizard an option for you? I think in your situation it would be close to the auto-magic solution you seek. You would need to restore the empty schema and use the wizard afterward.

Comment: @TheDemonLord That's the advise for how to do it for a single table, which was your original question. You don't really need to "go through each column on each table" -- you can just indiscriminately `SET IDENTITY INSERT ON/OFF` as you loop through tables.

Comment: I did some additional testing on how many tables were out of sync, in the end - it was only 2 tables (my bad - I thought it was going to be much worse than that) - so I used that solution in the end- apologies for my previous comment - had wasted a whole day on it and wasn't feeling very chipper.

Answer (score 0):

To close this out @amtwo 's solution SET IDENTITY_INSERT tab1 ON/OFF was the solution.